# creating a responsive menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, responsive

hopefully someone is able to help. i have been trying to create a simple menu thats responsive. i have the following code here

```
<nav class="menu">
<ul class="active">
    <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>

<a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>


<form class="search-form">
    <input type="text">
    <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

});

and i cant seem to add my CSS however here is the full thing on codepen

https://codepen.io/inzid/pen/NjvGjG

as you can see the desktop version is fine but when you change down to a mobile the dropdown doesnt work.

any ideas?

Comment: You neglected to embed jQuery in your codepen …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
/*----- Toggle Button -----*/

.toggle-nav {
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}


/*----- Menu -----*/

@media screen and (min-width: 860px) {
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #303030;
  }
}

.menu ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.menu a {
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #FFF;
  transition: color linear 0.15s;
}

.menu a:hover,
.menu .current-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #66a992;
}


/*----- Search -----*/

.search-form {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.search-form input {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  outline: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.search-form button {
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0px 7px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 0px 2px 2px 0px;
  background: #66a992;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*----- Responsive -----*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 90%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
  .search-form input {
    width: 120px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .menu ul.active {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120%;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #303030;
  }
  .menu ul:after {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 22px;
    content: '';
    transform: translate(0%, -100%);
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #303030;
  }
  .menu li {
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
  }
  .toggle-nav {
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #303030;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #777;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: color linear 0.15s;
  }
  .toggle-nav:hover,
  .toggle-nav.active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #66a992;
  }
  .search-form {
    margin: 12px 0px 0px 20px;
    float: left;
  }
  .search-form input {
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="active">
    <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>

  <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>


  <form class="search-form">
    <input type="text">
    <button>Search</button>
  </form>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't added jQuery in your pen. Add that and it works.